# Is there a way to increase the spacing between header tags?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I currently have this HTML

```html
<h2 class="adsl-heading heading" id="adsl-heading-seven"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i>Yurt dışıyla konuşuyorum.</h2>                        
<h2 class="adsl-heading heading" id="adsl-heading-eight"><i class="fas fa-signal"></i>Online görüşün.</h2>
```

I want to increase the space between them slightly but when I use margin they push each other away by a lot, is there a way to do it without margin? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide css file you are using. It will be really helpful. You can increase the space between by using following approach.
Padding
Margin
Line-height

Comment: you can use padding, line-height, transform, br tag. But it depends on your css and your html, on how you use margin and on the units of measurement. you need to give us more information.

Comment: Can you make a minimal, working code snippet?

Comment: What's with the italic tags, that don't even enclose any text?

Comment: try using line-height

Comment: @MikeBrockington They appear to be [Font Awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/).